# Hybrid column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create something like "hybrid column" in SQLAlchemy model?

When I have the following model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String(50))
    lastname = Column(String(50))

    # I tried both, hybrid_property and hybrid_method but nothing works in my case
    @hybrid_property
    def fullname(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
```

Then I would like to use this hybrid column in query like:

```
db.query(User.fullname).filter(...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: From the documentation it seems it is possible. What error are you getting?

Comment: Just now I don't have access to my PC but it had something to do with InstrumentedAttribute and the problem was that in def fullname() decorated method I couldn't access to self param and print like 

        self.firstname

was returning User.firstname to me.